# SQL Query within PHP code does not write the correct information to database

Tags: php, sql

I have two query's one that is supposed to update existing data, and one 
that is supposed to insert new data. The insert query is inserting the 
wrong data though. It is inserting the data that is being sent to the 
update query.

I have tried moving the function that has the insert query to different 
files. The same problem still exists. Interestingly enough, if I comment 
out the update query, the insert query will work perfect. As of now, the 
update query works fine. Another interesting issue is the alert right 
below the insert query does not work. I have not been able to get it to 
show up at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// update query
mssql_query("UPDATE ERP_VIEW.dbo.NCRfaults SET faultID = $riptionold[$f]', 
rcID = '$firstchar', qty = '$faultqtyold[$f]'
WHERE ncrID = '$ncr_id'");

// insert query
<?php
    $q2 = "INSERT INTO ERP_VIEW.dbo.NCRfaults (ncrID, faultID, rcID, qty)
    VALUES ('$ncr_id','$fdescription[$f]', '$firstchar2', '$faultqty[$f]')";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("<?php echo $q2; ?>")
</script>

<?php

 mssql_query($q2);
```

Comment: Try using prepared statement. I think it should fix your issue. `SET faultID = riptionold[$f]` seems buggy, `riptionold` is some kind of SQL array as it's definitely not PHP `$riptionold[$f]`? Also **SQL Injection** warning!

Comment: As @Justinas says, don't ever use this code on a live website! ***SQL Injection!***

Comment: Where are you actually running the insert query? You're only creating a string. The update query is the only one being sent to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the replies everyone! I will try a prepared statement and see if that works. @aynber I'm sorry I missed the part where the query is run. I just edited the question and it's in there now. It is the next line below the insert query!

Comment: @Justinas riptionold is PHP I forgot the $ when typing out the question. It's an array that is defined earlier, and in my testing with JS alerts it has the correct value. Sorry for any confusion that created there.

Comment: @KJWork So what does it contains? Does it need quotes around too?

Answer (score 0):

Well everyone, I figured it out. I am very sorry to have wasted anyones time. I really appreciate all of the reply's.  I called the insert, and then the update. So I was updating right over the fresh insert.